# Heroku deployment failing after making requirements.txt file

Tags: heroku, flask

I have a flask application, that I want to push to Heroku, but is failing. I get the error:

```
 Requested runtime (python-3.5.1) is not available for this stack
```

I looked into my runtime.txt file:

```
python-3.6.5
```

which seems to be the right version of python.

in my requirements.txt I have this:

```
Flask==0.12.0
Jinja2==2.8.1
gunicorn==19.6.0
```

I only use Flask and Jinja so far.

How come I still get this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you commit your changes in your dependency files before you push to Heroku.